# How to get Field Name with maximum value in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Suppose I  have following collection,

```json
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("630670832c07f66261eb80c9"),
    "name" : "Suresh",
    "math" : 80.0,
    "sci" : 75.0,
    "hindi" : 96.0,
    "physics" : 74.0
}
```

Question:-
I want to know maximum marks with **subject name**

I know, maximum marks can get by `{$max : ["$math","$sci","$hindi","$physics" ]`
But I don't know how I got the **corresponding subject Name as well**.

Comment: Using any data as field names is widely considered an anti-pattern with MongoDB.  You can see how it complicates queries.  Perhaps a better data model would be something like `"courses": [ {"subject": "math", "marks": 80.0}, {"subject": "sci", "marks": 75.0}, {"subject": "hindi", "marks": 96.0}, {"subject": "physics", "marks": 74.0} ]`.

Answer (score 0):

With MongoDB v5.2+, you can perform `$sortArray` on the k-v tuples array obtained from `$objectToArray`.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "output": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": {
            "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT"
          },
          "as": "kv",
          "cond": {
            "$in": [
              "$$kv.k",
              [
                "math",
                "sci",
                "hindi",
                "physics"
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "output": {
        "$sortArray": {
          input: "$output",
          sortBy: {
            v: -1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "output": {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          "$output",
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "output": "$output.k"
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iGUndOyarFd) for your reference.